# What is a recommended grant expiry time in Oauth2?

Tags: redis, oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect

We've had a longstanding bug with our app that uses the Oauth2 protocol. We have a server running Node with the `oidc-provider` package, and also a Redis instance which stores refresh tokens, grants etc. using [the Redis adapter example](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/main/example/adapters/redis.js) in the `oidc-provider` package.

We have a client application which is a native app, and it uses the normal flow to sign in and obtain a refresh token plus access token. Thereafter, it uses the refresh token to obtain new access tokens every hour (if the application remains open that long) or when the app is next opened. Refresh tokens are stored in an OS-specific secure keychain, and have an expiry of 30 days.

The ideal UX of our app would be that a user only has to sign in explicitly once, and should then remain signed in. So we have a daemon that runs once per day to use the refresh token, as well as to do some ancillary tasks.

Our bug was that we were seeing `grant is invalid` errors quite commonly. We've traced it to the fact that the [aforementioned Redis adapter](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/main/example/adapters/redis.js) doesn't actually extend the life of the grant (which we currently give an expiry of 2 weeks) correctly. As well as the `grant:{id}` key, we also find a `Grant:{id}` key in our Redis database, and this was not having its life extended on `upsert`, meaning it will expire in two weeks.

We think that by extending the Redis TTL of `Grant:{id}` and also updating the `exp` field in its value we could have the grant live forever.

So we now face a question: is it ok to change the adapter to make the grant indefinitely extendable? Or is this bad security practice? Is our ideal UX of 'just log in once' a bad idea?

Comment: 'Is our ideal UX of 'just log in once' a bad idea?' - yes, it's not just bad, it's horrible for security. Zero applications out there today follow this. Just why?

Comment: I use lots of applications where I logged in once and then never had to again. Slack, Whatsapp, Linear, iCloud, etc. I've never had to re-log into these at random intervals.

Comment: Yes but they refresh the token in the background. They don’t just give you a limitless one if that makes sense? Refresh more often as opposed to extending beyond 2 weeks for example.

Comment: We don't give limitless tokens - we refresh them in the background too. What I'm saying is that refreshing the token doesn't extend the grant. So when the grant expires, the refresh token can no longer be used, and the user is functionally signed out. In the end we extended the grant length because customers found it very confusing to be signed out for no reason if they didn't launch the app for a few weeks.